# Display power consumption ratio of smartphones and smart watches

Tags: wearable, smartphones

What is the most power-consuming part of your smartphone or smartwatch display?  Or is it cpu?  Naturally I think that it will change depending on the situation, but general use is assumed.

Comment: If you want to get a general idea, on what is or has been using a lot of power in your smartphone, you could look under `Settings|Energy`, where you could see percentage-wise the display or the apps or the core-OS components that might have been using a lot of power in the last 3 hours or since the last recharge. Of course, it doesn't break down this chart sensor-wise or per hardware component. But it still gives you an intuitive feeling on what was consuming how much power. You can match up then your activity at that time, and see that table and your action on the phone agree with each other.

Comment: thanks for your commet!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you previously said, it depends much in which situation your smartphone or smartwatch is at the moment.

In [this article](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/atc10/tech/full_papers/Carroll.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwj31vaYudnjAhVwE7kGHdE4ACkQFjAAegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw3Vgx3p7ukQd-l6YmlV5mdG) you can see some interesting data on power consumption for most parts of a smartphone considering many scenarios:

- In **suspended** mode (scenario in which the smartphone stays most of time with backlight off, but ready to receive call, wifi, etc...) the most power consuming parts are, in order: GSM, CPU and graphics.
- In **Idle** mode (when the smartphone is "awake" but no app is actively being used) almost 50% of the power consumption comes just from the screen (graphics and LCD) considering the backlight off. The GSM (22%) and CPU are the next biggest consumers.

**Obs:** Notice that the power consumption of the screen grows exponentially with the brightness level, so you might have different results depending on that factor. As example, In idle state, if the backlight is at its maximum brightness, it can reach 80% of the total consumption.

- **During a call**, the GSM dominates the power consumption, followed by the screen and CPU.

What about an entire day?

- In a **scenario of an average day** where you have to make regular calls,  the main consumers are, in order, the GSM, CPU and Graphics.

Comment: thanks!!!!i would read pdf.